# react-native init specify react version and react-native version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, version

I basically want to init a react-native project with react@15.6.0 and react-native@0.45.0 because dependency problems. However react-native command only allows me to specify react-native version:

```
react-native init sample --version react-native@0.45.0
```

This command not works:

```
react-native init diskful --version react-native@0.45.0 --version react@15.6.0
```

This, too:

```
react-native init diskful --version react-native@0.45.0 react@15.6.0
```

And this, too:

```
react-native init diskful --version react@15.6.0 react-native@0.45.0
```

Install globally react@15.6.0 or react-native@0.45.0 does not affect.
Please, someone help me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a project :

```
react-native init MyNewApp --version 0.45.0
```

If you want do change version then try with this:

```
npm install --save react-native@0.44.0
npm install --save react@16.0.0-alpha.6
```

Comment: Could you give me a advise on which are most stable versions of react and react-native now :) thank you

Comment: @user2732952 react-native version is 0.44 and react - 16.0.0-alpha.6. react-native@0.45.0 iOS project has some build issue due to xcode 8.3.2. Try with 0.46 or 0.44. It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. delete node_modules folder
2. Edit Package.json

   "dependencies": {
       "react": "15.6.0",
       "react-native": "0.45.0",
    },
3. run command 'npm install'

Answer (score 0):

You could initiate the app using

```
react-native init --version="0.45.0" yourapp,
```

If further changes are needed, make changes in `package.json` in react or react-native fields and simply do `npm install`